# how to crawl website having static url in python

Tags: php, python, web-crawler, dynamic-url

I want to crawl a PHP based website it have a search box we can enter a number in that search box, it renders a the result against the entered number when we click submit button or hit enter but URL does not change.
like its showing foo.com/res_17.php for every result but for crawling like more than thousand records, records should be accessible by unique IDs such as foo.com/res_17.php?id=1001, foo.com/res_17.php?id=1002 - foo.com/res_17.php?id=3450 so that i can access them using while loop how can I do this any solution please help.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: http://fbise.edu.pk/res-ssc-II.php on this website results for roll# 100001-143293 are available how to crawl them...?

Answer (score 0):

I gave you one my script

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a",
            href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$")):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

Output is presented as all Andrew Ng Wikipedia's articles.